# how to Add 6 days to current date?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my js. now , when the date is february 28, the 7th day will be 35.
how can I fix my js code?
I want to display the exact date from now up to 7th day.

```js
//Get Upcoming Bookings Current Date
getUpcomingBookingsCurrenDate = () => {
  let currentDate = Date.now();
  let day = new Date(currentDate).getDate();
  let day2 = day + 1;
  let day3 = day + 2;
  let day4 = day + 3;
  let day5 = day + 4;
  let day6 = day + 5;
  let day7 = day + 6;
  document.getElementById('day1').innerHTML = day;
  document.getElementById('day2').innerHTML = day2;
  document.getElementById('day3').innerHTML = day3;
  document.getElementById('day4').innerHTML = day4;
  document.getElementById('day5').innerHTML = day5;
  document.getElementById('day6').innerHTML = day6;
  document.getElementById('day7').innerHTML = day7;
}
getUpcomingBookingsCurrenDate();
```

```html
First 7 date from today
<br>
<span id='day1'></span>
<span id='day2'></span>
<span id='day3'></span>
<span id='day4'></span>
<span id='day5'></span>
<span id='day6'></span>
<span id='day7'></span>
```

Comment: Try http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: @NickSavenia that is a huge overkill when setDate(getDate()+1) will do the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/36ohbfus/